Create an image of a drive of compueter running windows 10 to configure multiple computers
At my workplace, we have to configure multiple computers with exact same hardware specs. We need to install our proprietary software on all of them one by one which takes lots of time.
I'm looking for a solution where I can fully configure one computer and create an image of the disk drive, which I can use on multiple computers using windows recovery option.
If not image, what other options I have?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Microsoft offers provisioning packages, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-packages, "for IT administrators to configure end-user devices without imaging...  easily specify the desired configuration and settings required to enroll the devices into management. Then, apply that configuration to target devices in a matter of minutes. It's best suited for... deployments... from tens to a few hundred computers."

What you require is possible. Install the software, create a Windows Image of the machine with DISM, then apply the image to other systems. This process is more complicated then an answer can explain but it’s not technically complicated.
